# determining whether the given sentence contain the given word or not c++

Tags: c++, regex, string, substring

I need to determine whether a given word is found in an another string or not in c++.

my function prototype will be like `bool check(string sentence, string word);`

and "sentence" could be like : `word.someWord AND/OR/XOR word2.someWord *AND/OR/XOR* word3.someWord` and goes like that.

For a real example: *unlock_the_door.value=1 AND turn_of_car.checkSum=1*

Now, In this example If I assign word to lock, my check function should be return false but If I give it to "unlock" it should return true.

To do that I've used to .find() function but as you all know it was wrong because it returned me to true even if I give lock as an word parameter since "unlock" contains "lock"

I guess I need to use regular expression but I dont know how to do that. Is there anyone to help me ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: May I ask what is the reason of -1  ?

Comment: You are not posing an attempted solution and asking a question on it; you are proposing a solution and asking SO to implement it for your (at least, that's what it looks like, to me). Before you can use a regex-based implementation, you should understand at least _some_ regex syntax; otherwise, any solutions you get will probably be unusable (or usable but very brittle) for you. Either way, are you asking about the C++ regex API, the actual regular expression syntax to use, or something else?

Comment: @utnapistim actually I need to know is there a way to do that without using regex

Comment: There is; You can tokenize the string and process each token (see answer by @SteveBarnes), you can write a statefull forward parser for your buffer (implemented as a FSM - more efficient but more complicated/error prone), you can use regex (high abstraction level) or a combination of the above.

Comment: I would use a combination: first tokenize the expression into terms( "unlock_the_door.value=1", "AND", "turn_of_car.checkSum=1" ), then apply a regex on the identifier in each of the terms. It is not the most efficient, but it is a good separation of concerns and easy to alter/extend later. (If you have to do this in a very demanding environment, consider writing a per-character single-pass parser (as a FSM)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use C++11 `regex_search` using as search pattern your word surrounded by either a word boundary (`\b`) or an underscore.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool check(const string &sentence, const string &word) {
    string boundary = "(_|\\b)";
    return regex_search(sentence, regex(boundary + word + boundary));
}

int main () {
    string sentence = "unlock_the_door.value=1 AND turn_of_car.checkSum=1";
    cout << check(sentence, "lock") << endl;
    cout << check(sentence, "unlock") << endl;
}
```

If you don't want to use C++11 or you are using a compiler that doesn't support C++11 regex (e.g. gcc versions prior to 4.9.0), you can use the [Boost library](http://www.boost.org/). You just need to download the library and add these two lines to your source:

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
using namespace boost;
```

Also remember to pass the option `-lboost_regex` to gcc.

Answer (score 1):

First split your sentence into words, then check the list to see if it contains the exact word(s) you are looking for.

You could also consider using regular expressions and looking for your word(s) each preceded by any of line start or space and followed by any of space, punctuation or end of line.

Comment: @Steve_Barnes thanks for reply, If I split my sentence into words, for the example above it will be like word1=unlock_tw_door.value=1  word2=And word3=turn_of_car.checkSum=1 and again find funciton will return true for the lock word since word1 contains it.

Comment: A was expecting you to _match_ words in the list not use find on word in the list. "unlock" != "lock"

Answer (score 1):

I mean that underscores are blanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>


bool check( const std::string &sentence, const std::string &word )
{
   std::istringstream is( sentence );

   return std::find( std::istream_iterator<std::string>( is ),
                     std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
                     word ) != std::istream_iterator<std::string>();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << check( "unlock the door.value=1 AND turn of car.checkSum=1", "lock" )
              << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << check( "unlock the door.value=1 AND turn of car.checkSum=1", "unlock" )
              << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
false
true
```

If the underscores are not blanks then you can use the same `std::istringstream` and standard function `std::getline` and check each read string whether it is equal to the given string.

Or you can indeed split the sentence into an object of type `std::vector<std::string>` using member function `find_first_of`

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>


bool check( const std::string &sentence, const std::string &word )
{
    const char *delimiters = " _=.";
    std::string::size_type first, last;
    bool found = false;

    first = 0;
    while ( !found && first != std::string::npos )
    {
        first = sentence.find_first_not_of( delimiters, first );

        if ( first != std::string::npos )
        {
            last = sentence.find_first_of( delimiters, first );
            found = sentence.substr( first, last == std::string::npos ? last : last - first ) == word;
            first = last;
        }
    }

    return found;
}

int main()
{
    std::string s = "unlock_the_door.value=1 AND turn_of_car.checkSum=1";

    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << check( s, "lock" )
              << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << check( s, "unlock" )
              << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
false
true
```

Comment: @Vlad_from_Moscow underscores are not blanks they're part of the word. However I couldnt your suggestion for this could you edit it according to it ?

Answer (score 0):

Split the sentence by underscore as delimitor.
And use stricmp function.
Probably that should solve.

Comment: I guess you dont understand my question so dont push it please

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right you want to see whether not only the word is contained in the sentence but also in words within this sentence.
You can do it like this:

```
bool check (std::string sentence, std::string word)
{
    std::string part;
    for(unsigned int ii=0; ii<sentence.size()-word.size(); ii++)
    {
        part = sentence.substr(ii,word.size());
        if(!part.compare(word)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This checks every part of the sentence which has length word.size() if it equals the word. If it equals this will return true, otherwise false.

Ok, what I wrote before is maybe exactly what you don't want. If you only want to compare to words in the sentence (whatever is a word for you, you have to think about the delimiters) then you can do it like this (you need to include string.h):

```
bool check (std::string sentence, std::string word)
{
char *c_str_sentence = new char[sentence.size()+1]; //you need this cause string.c_str() will return const char* but strtok needs char*;
char *c_str_word = new char[word.size()+1];

strcpy(c_str_sentence,sentence.c_str());
strcpy(c_str_word,word.c_str());

bool is_contained = false;

const char *delimiters = " _=.";    //any delimiter you wish;

char *part = strtok(c_str_sentence,delimiters);
while (part != NULL)
{
    if(!strcmp(part,c_str_word)) {
        is_contained = true;
        break;
    }
    part = strtok(NULL,delimiters);
}

delete[] c_str_sentence;
delete[] c_str_word;

return is_contained;
}
```

Returns only true if you check for "unlock" not for "lock". However by specifying the delimiters you can specify what you want to be treated as a word and what you don't.

Comment: Your second function will leak memory every time it's called. It allocates memory with `new[]` and never releases it with `delete[]`.